# How to find the SQL statements that caused tempdb growth?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tempdb

The tempdb of a server (SQL Server 2008) increases to 500GB+ several times every month. Is it possible to find out which SQL statements caused this problem? The problem is usually not caused by `create table #temp...; insert into #temp...` or `select ... into #temp...` but complex joins.

The *Initial Size* of some of the tempdb files is also automatically set to much bigger values every time. How to prevent it?

Sometime the cached plans prevent resizing/shrinking the files. How to find which one hold the tempdb?

Comment: Sorry it's almost 2 AM and I'm out of gas to answer this question completely, however these URLs may come in handy while you wait for other answers - http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1432/tempdb-configuration-best-practices-in-sql-server/ and http://www.google.com/search?q=which+queries+are+using+tempdb

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are three DMVs you can use to track tempdb usage:

- [sys.dm_db_task_space_usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190288.aspx)
- [sys.dm_db_session_space_usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187938.aspx)
- [sys.dm_db_file_space_usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174412.aspx)

The first two will allow you to track allocations at a query & session level. The third tracks allocations across version store, user and internal objects.

The following example query will give you allocations per session:

```
SELECT
  sys.dm_exec_sessions.session_id AS [SESSION ID]
  ,DB_NAME(database_id) AS [DATABASE Name]
  ,HOST_NAME AS [System Name]
  ,program_name AS [Program Name]
  ,login_name AS [USER Name]
  ,status
  ,cpu_time AS [CPU TIME (in milisec)]
  ,total_scheduled_time AS [Total Scheduled TIME (in milisec)]
  ,total_elapsed_time AS    [Elapsed TIME (in milisec)]
  ,(memory_usage * 8)      AS [Memory USAGE (in KB)]
  ,(user_objects_alloc_page_count * 8) AS [SPACE Allocated FOR USER Objects (in KB)]
  ,(user_objects_dealloc_page_count * 8) AS [SPACE Deallocated FOR USER Objects (in KB)]
  ,(internal_objects_alloc_page_count * 8) AS [SPACE Allocated FOR Internal Objects (in KB)]
  ,(internal_objects_dealloc_page_count * 8) AS [SPACE Deallocated FOR Internal Objects (in KB)]
  ,CASE is_user_process
             WHEN 1      THEN 'user session'
             WHEN 0      THEN 'system session'
  END         AS [SESSION Type], row_count AS [ROW COUNT]
FROM 
  sys.dm_db_session_space_usage
INNER join
  sys.dm_exec_sessions
ON  sys.dm_db_session_space_usage.session_id = sys.dm_exec_sessions.session_id
```

If you want to track usage over a period of time, consider collecting data with [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com), as demonstrated by [Kendra Little](http://www.littlekendra.com/2011/02/01/whoisactive/).

Comment: Thanks. Is the difference of `[SPACE Allocated FOR USER Objects (in KB)]` and `[SPACE Deallocated FOR USER Objects (in KB)]` the actual occupied space of the session?

Answer (score 4):

There can be various sources of a problem:

- usage of table variables or temporary tables
- sql server created intermediate resultsets as worktables in tempdb - usually for sorting purposes (usually is a sign of absent indexes/out-of-date statistics)
- sql server decided to pre-evaluate the resultset of table valued function and in this case it stores the data in tempdb
- recreating indexes with option `SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON`

Answer (score 3):

I am using [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15)

Select the Metric as "Temp DB Memory Used (KB)" and Statistic as "Max".

Then I found the boy who kill my TempDB.

***update** : I have checked the Query store feature, it is not available for SQL Server 2008.*

[image]

Comment: We enabled Query Store but we can't see `Temp DB Memory Used` in the drop-down. How did you make it appear in there @Tajmahals?

Comment: @AkiraYamamoto I believed the TempDB measure are available since SQL Server 2016. The SQL Server 2014 may not.

Comment: tks, we are using SQL Server 2016 tho